# Macro return value

Tags: c++, macros

Can macro return an object?

```
#define macro1 {obj1}
```

Since macro is text substitution, could I use macro like macro1.function1()?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you tell us the bigger problem you're trying to solve, not the step.

Comment: @GManNickG Maybe he's just curious to know what's possible...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A macro never returns anything. A macro returns textual representation of code that will be pasted into the place of the program where it is used before compilation.

Read about the [C Preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).

So:

```
#define macro1 {obj1}

int main() {
  macro1
}
```

... will be compiled as if you wrote

```
int main() {
  {obj1}
}
```

It's just textual substitution, that can optionally take a parameter.

---

If you're using GCC you can take a look at what the program will look like after preprocessing, using the `cpp` tool:

```
# cpp myprog.cpp myprog.cpp_out
```

Generally mixing macro's with objects is bad practice, use [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) instead.

---

One known usage of macro's in terms of objects is using them to access singletons (however that isn't such a nice idea in general):

```
#define LOGGER Logger::getLogger()

...

LOGGER->log("blah");
```

You could also use the preprocessor to choose at compile time the object you want to use:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#  define LOGGER DebugLogger
#else
#  define LOGGER Logger
#end

// assuming that DebugLogger and Logger are objects not types
LOGGER.log("blah");
```

... but the forementioned templates do that better.

Comment: Thanks. So could I use macro1.function in the example above?

Comment: Yes, but that would be bad practice. There's one situation in which it is used however, I'll add it to the description.

Comment: Your example wouldn't work however, because the `obj` is in `{}` braces.

Comment: +1 for suggestion to use `cpp` -- very useful for preproccessor debugging.

Answer (score 6):

A macro triggers a textual substitution during the preprocessing step (part of the seven phases of compilation). Returning a value occurs at runtime. The question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

The macro of your example replaces the text `macro1` with `{obj1}`. It only replaces text with other text; it doesn't know the concept of objects, or classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can always see what does the compiler do when you define a macro(and call it).The code of the macro is simply replaced (just like copy paste).
compile with gcc -E.
For example for this code

```
#define macro1 {obj1}

int main() {
int obj1;
macro1
}
```

On compiling with **gcc -E example.c** i get the following output

```
# 1 "macro.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "macro.c"



int main() {
int obj1;
{obj1} //here your call gets expanded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function macro are not real functions in the sense of C++ function: they are just preprocessing instructions.

Your source file is first read by the preprocessor, the macro are processed (expanded, replaced, etc.) and the resulting source is then given to the compiler.

So macro are not much more than just 'copy paste' of text in your source file. So you can use macro containing a `return` statement but it will just be replaced in your code.

See also [Function-like macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function_002dlike-Macros.html#Function_002dlike-Macros)

Answer (score 0):

### Context

I had a function:

```
bool CheckAndContinue(const bool p_test,
                      const std::string& p_errorMessage)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(p_test, p_errorMessage.c_str());
    return p_test;
}
```

for which, since BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE is in a function, result would always point to line in this function whereas issue is actually on line where `CheckAndContinue` is called.

I then had to do a macro that can do the same thing so that line pointed is where `CheckAndContinue` was called, that leads to the answer below for my specific case.

### Answer (GCC only as I understood because of `({ ... })` usage)

```
#define CHECK_AND_CONTINUE(p_test, p_errorMessage)\
({\
    const bool result = (p_test);\
    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(result, p_errorMessage);\
    result;\
})
```

Note I pass by `const bool result = (p_test)` because if I call for instance `const bool success = CHECK_AND_CONTINUE(TimeConsumingFunctionOrFunctionThatModifyAValue(param))`, if I had:

```
#define CHECK_AND_CONTINUE(p_test, p_errorMessage)\
({\
    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(p_test, p_errorMessage);\
    p_test;\
})
```

because of how macro works, `TimeConsumingFunctionOrFunctionThatModifyAValue(param)` would have been called twice (at both `p_test` usage) and then time consuming would have consumed twice and if modifying a value would have modified twice (a simple increment of a value would have incremented twice for instance).